# How do I permute each stack in a 3D matrix according to indices in another 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation, octave

Okay, suppose I have a 3D matrix A and another 3D matrix Inds. What I would like to do is, for each stack `A(i,j,:)`, permute that stack according to the indices given in `Inds(i,j,:)`. Thus, if `A(i,j,:)` is `[1.5 2.5 3.5]` and `Inds(i,j,:)` is `[3 2 1]` then A`(i,j,:)` becomes `[3.5 2.5 1.5]`.

Yes, I know `A(i,j,:)` is not a vector in Octave. Consider it shorthand for `permute(A, [1 3 2])(i,:,j)`.

This should be simple, but for whatever reason I can't seem to find the function to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matlab its quite simple:

```
A(i,j,:) = A(i,j,Inds(i,j,:));
```

In Matlab you can rearrange any vector using a vector of indices:

```
A = [10 20 30 40 50 60];
B = [6 5 4 1 2 3];
A = A(B);
```

`A` is now `[60 50 40 10 20 30]`

If `A` is `MxNxP`, when you use `A(i,j,:)` notation you are essentially dealing with a `Px1` vector that you can manipulate at will.

Comment: If this is the case, then it seems there is no choice except to use a nested loop to iterate over i and j. Unless there is a better way?